# Httparty retorna 502 mas execução no Postman funciona

Tags: api, ruby, testes, testes-automatizados

Eu faço alguns testes de APIS com o httparty e uso o postman pra teste de fumaça.

Quando eu chamo o mesmo processo na minha classe ruby, usando httparty, ele me da 502, se em segundos eu rodar no postman, ele me da 200 e retorna o response que preciso.

Postman:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Httparty:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from features/api/GetCosmic.rb:33:in `<main>'
features/api/GetCosmic.rb:16:in `cosmic': API não funcionou. Código: 502 (RuntimeError)
```

```rb
def cosmic(read_key,marca,opcao) 
        inicio = 0
        fim = 100
        array = []
        while(inicio <= fim)
            response = HTTParty.get("https://api.cosmicjs.com/v1/#{marca}/objects?type=#{opcao}&hide_metafields=true&pretty=true&skip=#{inicio}&limit=#{fim}&read_key=#{read_key}",
                :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
            if response.code != 200
               raise "API não funcionou. Código: #{response.code.to_s}"
               break
            else
                break if response['objects'].nil?
                response['objects'].each do |obj|
                    array.push(obj)
                end
               inicio = fim+1
               fim = fim+100  
            end
        end
        array
    end
```